# Asking the reason of two related statements in one "why" sentence

Tags: questions, word-order, sentence-choice

Suppose I want to say

> Why does your method work?  Why doesn't mine work?

in one sentence.  Shoud I say

> Why does your method work but mine doesn't?

or

> Why does your method work but doesn't mine?

Comment: _But_ is awkward here. Instead: _Why does your method work **while** mine doesn't?_

Comment: Thanks.  So do you mean I should use the first sentence (with "but" changed to "while"), and the second is wrong?

Comment: Correct. You only invert the order for the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does your method work but mine doesn't?

and

> Why does your method work while mine doesn't?

They're both absolutely fine because that's how native speakers typically say it. Though, some might argue that the second way sounds a little bit better.

Comment: Why are they fine? What's wrong with the other option? Please make your answer more helpful by explaining rather than making statements.